# BroadcastReceiver starting Activity with random delay

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, delay, start-activity

I'm working on an alarm clock and I have a serious problem, the BroadCastReceiver **always** gets called **exactly in time**, I do some work like getting intent extras, nothing heavy or long and then I call the alarm activity.

There is very strange behavoir in there, many times it just works fine, but sometimes **the Activity Call gets delayed** and I'm talking about **1-13 minutes** in my tests so far, which is totally unacceptable for an alarm app.
This happens when the device gets woken up from doze mode.

I'm using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` which really works like a charm when calling the receiver, but the Activity start from the receiver does not.

Here's a part of the receiver code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("Ben", "Alarmreceiver HELLO");

[...]

Log.d("Ben", "Alarmreceiver CALLING WAKE SCREEN NOW");

        if (wait) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Log.d("Ben", "AlarmReceiver: Alarm still running, wait for finsihing...");

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3_000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        context.startActivity(new Intent("package.action.alarm").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                    }
                    context.startActivity(new Intent("package.action.alarm").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                }
            }).start();
        }

        else
            context.startActivity(new Intent("package.action.alarm").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

        Log.d("Ben", "Call done.");
    }
//end of receiver
```

Here is what I get from LogCat:

```
06-24 20:50:02.623 6527-6527/package D/Ben: Alarmreceiver HELLO
06-24 20:50:02.753 6527-6527/package D/Ben: Alarmreceiver CALLING WAKE SCREEN NOW
06-24 20:50:02.794 6527-6527/package D/Ben: Call done.
06-24 20:55:09.129 6527-6527/package D/Ben: AlarmActivity.onCreate()
```

As you can see there is a delay of 5 minutes between the command and the actual activity start!

One can see that the "call done" Log.d is reached after less than 200ms.
The runnable should not be a problem, since it hasen't even been started in this case. (It only waits for a previously running alarm to be ended if one was running)

The Log.d of `AlarmActivity.onCreate()` is the very first statement in the AlarmActivity, right after that I acquire wakelocks.

I tried: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);` since I found it here in another post, but no change in behavior at all.

That's really frustrating - does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix it?

**EDIT**

Now that I exchanged the new Thread with the following code:

```
final PendingResult result = goAsync();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            context.startActivity(new Intent("package.action.alarm").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

            Log.d("Ben", "Runnable done.");
            result.finish();
        }
    }, 2_000);
```

everything **seems** to be working fine.
I ran 5 long term tests today where I set up an alarm for +50 or 60 minutes each, to make sure the system is surely in doze mode (I don't trust the adb force doze mode):

The first 3 runs with the `goAsync` ran perfectly in time.

The fourth run, where I changed the code back to the Thread without going Async explicitly was more than 4 minutes late again.

The fifth test with `postDelayed` and `goAsync` was perfectly in time again.

**I consider this now as working reliably as long it does not ring too late again.
Thousand thanks to Jonas!!! I have been fighting with this issue for MONTHS, thinking a new Thread would be asynchronously enough ;)**

**EDIT 2:**

I have now tested all that for 1 more week and it's still not working nicely.
After I changed my runnable to:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.startActivity(new Intent("package.action.alarm").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                Log.d("Ben", "Activity has been called.");

// give an extra 4.5 sec window to start activity and alarm stream...
                Handler h = new Handler();
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.finish();
                        Log.d("Ben", "Allowing Rec. finish now...");
                    }
                }, 4_500);
            }
        }, 2_000);
```

it works okay, but not for 100%. (The 2 seconds are to finish an already running alarm and with the 4.5 seconds I'm hoping to give the Activity and Service enough time to start the stream, then it will work fine)

Additional Info:

**The Receiver is starting an Activity and the first action there is to acquire Wakelocks (wifi and power) and forcing the screen on.
After that I do phone call handling and after that I start a foreground service which will stream music.**

I have Log.d's all over the place and can see, that sometimes, when the stream buffers too long - so that the 4.5 seconds in the BR have passed, the device falls asleep and does not start streaming music until a random time has passed again (maintenance window I guess) EVEN IF WAKELOCKS HAVE BEEN ACQUIRED ALREADY.

**This has NOTHING to do with the Runnable, I now found out. I removed it and called the Activity straight at the end of the BR, resulting in an almost certain delay of a few minutes in the activity starting procedure. Without going Async - it falls asleep even faster...**

How am I supposed to start an Activity from a broadcastreceiver that does not fall asleep/dozed when the BR is finished?

This looks like a bug to me. Or I'm missing something very basic.
The screen is on and remains on, but the foreground streaming service sometimes starts after that delay (several minutes).

Same thing happens when I start a foreground-service from the BR. The foreground-service sometimes stops in the middle of the onCreate, because of the BR is finishing and the device seems to be asleep (dozed)...

I'm really desperate.

When I gave 7.5 instead of 4.5 seconds to the second runnable in the BR I could notice ANRs in Google console. (Although I believe the alarm worked fine then).

What is the correct way to counter this problem? Starting an asyncTask?

**EDIT 3:**

Jonas, thanks for your answer again - I tried lots of different approaches the whole week and on my devices everything seems fine, but users report delays of up to 13 minutes still...

2 things I tried:

- starting a ForegroundService with notification and wakelocks as the only action in the AlarmReceiver and doing all the work inside the service
- removing the receiver and starting the AlarmActivity directly to get everything done as quickly as possible - grabbing wakelocks and forcing screen on as first thing in the activity, getting IntentExtras after that and starting the music StreamService as third thing (all that within 1-2 seconds)

this second approach is my current state and I thought it was working good, until someone reported a 13min delay again.

The ForegroundService did not work at all - it fell asleep very often before the music played... I only allowed this service to end when music already started playing, but this sometimes happened after the delay - I have no clue how? This cannot be correct, a foregroundService with wakelocks held MUST keep the device awake!?!?

(I would post the Activity but it consists of 750 lines so... no.)

**Anyway: what else can I do to REALLY keep/force the device out of the doze mode?**

1. setExactAndAllowWhileIdle **WORKS PERFECTLY**
2. getting wakelocks **works fine**
3. getting IntentExtras **seems working good**

sometime after that the device falls asleep although I got wakelocks and the screen is forced on.

4. music service gets started but does not finish buffering due to (I guess) doze mode again
5. music playback starts after x minutes

that's what I saw in the logs, now it runs fine 99% of the times, but rarely still occurs.
What am I missing? Is there a magic function to stop from dozing for x minutes?

Comment: I want to start the activity with a 3 second delay IF another alarm is still running (that time is used to stop the alarm service before starting it again). But in this case the thread is NOT started. The activity is called in the ELSE and should be up immediately. It seems like the system falls asleep again and actually starts the activity in the next maintenance window of the doze mode (which I believe is the random delay time).

Answer (score 1):

**Now I think this is fixed by rewriting the start-up procedure and going into a foregroundService directly.**

Regarding the delay:
I changed `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` to `setAlarmClock` recently and am now 100% sure the latter one **is late in doze mode (often) - good job for a user visible alarm function which has no other use case.**

It even was late when I `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` 10 seconds before alarm time and `setAlarmClock` to "now + 10 seconds". (1:55 minutes late....)

So now I am back to `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` **which always calls the BroadcastReceiver perfectly in time - always!**

I rewrote the whole startup procedure once again (had been changing it very often, since the failure did very randomly and rarely show up on my test devices)

**First (old) approach which worked well for a long time:**

`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` -> BroadcastReceiver -> AlarmActivity -> StreamingService (Foreground).

This ran good over months, but all of a sudden I had delays of 1-15 Minutes (maintenance window I guess) and the logs told me sometimes even the foreground service did start, the music (ExoPlayer) started buffering but was interrupted (by doze I guess) and continued buffering and playback after the random delay time.

Strange enough inside a ForegroundService, isn't it?

**My new approach:**

`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` -> BroadcastReceiver -> StreamService -> startActivity(AlarmActivity) -> (startForeground (the StreamService)) -> start streaming music

This worked on 3 different devices perfectly in all my tests for two days now and also in the mornings after a long doze period.

**BroadcastReceiver** (removed anything asynchronous here)

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("Ben", "AlarmReceiver HELLO");

    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    int intentId = 1909;

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, StreamService.class);
    if (b != null) {
        alarmIntent.putExtras(b);
        intentId = b.getInt("id");
        Log.d("Ben", "AlarmReceiver found ID: " + intentId);
    }

// CALC NEXT ALARM and start StreamingService...

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        context.startForegroundService(alarmIntent);
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, CalcNextAlarmService.class));
        Log.d("Ben", "SDK >= 26 *** context.startForegroundServices");
    }
    else {
        context.startService(alarmIntent);
        context.startService(new Intent(context, CalcNextAlarmService.class));
        Log.d("Ben", "SDK < 26 *** context.startServices");
    }
```

Additional info:

In the service I start the alarm screen activity in `onCreate()` and then the music stream inside `onStartCommand()` after `startForeground()`.

**I consider this now as my working solution until I notice otherwise.
Thanks for your help and suggestions, Jonas Lochmann!**

EDIT: The alarm has been late once again... I'll start a new clean post regarding a foregroundService affected by doze...